# Is there a way to assign a unique ID to each cell in AgGrid?

Tags: ag-grid

For testing purpose, there's an ask for adding ID's to each cell rendered in Ag-Grid. Is there any efficient way to assign ID's to each cell instead of looping over and manually assigning?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/226277).
Why would you need to set `id` for each cell if you could get the element using css selectors already rendered in [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid)?

You need to set `[getRowNodeId]` property for your [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid). when you set it to a function, the return value is considered as the `id` for the `row`.

```
  this._getRowNodeId = (item: any): string => {
    return `${item.id}`;
  };
```

Similarly, while providing `ColDef`, the value you set for `colId` property is considered as the `id` for the column.

So, after doing this, when you check the DOM, it would be rendered as below. Observe `row-id` and `col-id`.

```
<div row-id="113489" 
    role="row" row-index="6" comp-id="166"
    class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" 
    style="height: 28px; transform: translateY(168px);  ">

  <div col-id="10" 
       tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" comp-id="167"
       class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-with-height ag-cell-no-focus ag-cell-value" 
       style="width: 100px; left: 0px;  ">
    Cell_Value1
  </div>
  <div col-id="11" 
       tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" comp-id="167"
       class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-with-height ag-cell-no-focus ag-cell-value" 
       style="width: 100px; left: 0px;  ">
    Cell_Value2
  </div>
</div>
```

Hence, if you want to check the value inside the rendered cell for `row-id` and `col-id`, you can check it using selectors.